# Xcode - How to config a project for team working?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode8

I'm working on a team project using Git for versioning. All team members got a personal AppleID and bundle identifier. Every time one of us pushes some changes, others need to adjust their Bundle Identifiers and Team. This is where we need to change settings: [image]

Is there a way to work simultaneously on the same project under it versioning with our personal accounts?

Comment: The typical solution here would be to have one account own the app and invite the other developers to be members of that account (your Apple ID account can be a member of many teams at once). Is there a reason why you haven't done that?

Comment: I'm new in the Apple development. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll google about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should share a common Apple Developer account and add developers personal accounts though the common Apple Dev account. Then you will share the same bundle ID and Xcode's automatic signing will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold some variables in separate xcconfig files. Adding them to gitignore will prevent from committing them to repository